# i have a error in joomla - query please. i have and error in this query

Tags: sql, joomla

```
$datos = explode(';',$linea);
    $product_ean = trim($datos[0]);
    $product_price = trim($datos[1]);
    $name_es = trim($datos[2]);
    $short_description_es = trim($datos[3]);

    echo $product_ean,'<br>';
    echo $product_price,'<br>';
    echo $name_es ,'<br>';
    echo $short_description_es,'<br>';

    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $columns = array('product_id' ,'product_ean', 'product_price', 'name_es-ES', 'short_description_es-ES');
    $values = array(NULL, $product_ean, $product_price, $name_es, $short_description_es);

    $query
        ->insert($db->quoteName('vrg_jshopping_products'))
        ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
        ->values(implode(',', $values));

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->execute();
```

---

Error displaying the error page: Application Instantiation 
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '600,1000,articulo nuevo 1,Articulo de test 1)' at line 3

SQL=INSERT INTO `vrg_jshopping_products` (`product_id`,`product_ean`,`product_price`,`name_es-ES`,`short_description_es-ES`) VALUES (,600,1000,articulo nuevo 1,Articulo de test 1)

Comment: Try using  0 instead of Null for the values or just take out the field/values from the arrays and let it autoincrement.  Also use #__ instead of hardcoding the prefix.

Comment: for example: ?? please  =>  .use #__ instead of hardcoding the prefix. –

Comment: `vrg_jshopping_products` should be `#__jshopping_products` .. but you can see from the error message that the problem is you are inserting 4 values into 5 fields and have an extra comma too (due to the null).

Comment: the problem is the name of fields => 'name_es-ES', 'short_description_es-ES' but I do not know how to solve it, if I delete fields that works

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the name of the fields, they match the names in the array you created. the problem is 5 fields `product_id,product_ean,product_price,name_es-ES,short_description_es-ES`   and 4 values `,600,1000,articulo nuevo 1,Articulo de test 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting sql error because you have not quoted your values.You can use below code.

```
$columns = array('product_id' ,'product_ean', 'product_price', 'name_es-ES', 'short_description_es-ES');
$values = array(NULL, $product_ean, $product_price, $name_es, $short_description_es);


// Prepare the insert query.
$query
   ->insert($db->quoteName($table))
   ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
   ->values(implode(',', $db->quote($values)));
```

Comment: Why not `->values($db->quote($values));`?

Comment: @Elin  I did not know it accepts array as well.Thanks.